# PowerShell New-​Self​Signed​Certificate ip address

Tags: powershell, ssl-certificate

I am using New-​Self​Signed​Certificate to create ​certificate used for development purposes. I was able to create one for "DNS Name=localhost". I also want to support ip address range something like "IP.1 = 192.168.*.*" but i don't know how to pass it to the command? Is this supported at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IP address ranges are not supported by SAN extension (it is supported only in Name Constraints extension). When specifying an IP Address in the SAN, you have to specify unicast address. If you have multiple addresses, you have to explicitly specify all these addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add IP address *ranges*, but you can of course add multiple *single* IP addresses.

While you can add multiple DNS SANs with the `-DnsName` parameter of [`New-SelfSignedCertificate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/new-selfsignedcertificate), there is no parameter for IP address SANs. You have to do it more manually with the `-TextExtension` parameter. As `-DnsName` and `-TextExtension` (with SAN definition) are mutually exclusive, you then have to define your DNS SANs also within `-TextExtension`.

Here is an example, with a DNS name and three IP addresses:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -TextExtension @("2.5.29.17={text}DNS=localhost&IPAddress=127.0.0.1&IPAddress=::1&IPAddress=192.168.0.1")
```